# Не корректно работает генератор рандомных чисел

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день.

У меня не работает генератор рандомных чисел так, как мне хотелось. Обратите внимание на комментарии внутри кода JS. Проблема в том, что если на прямую в `var raund = Math.floor(Math.random() * (ot) + **вставить переменную ->** doo);` код не работает. А если как я указал в примере, работает, но не корректор. Только не ставьте в пример от 50 до 100, всё будет работать, а когда 444, 1244 - нет.

```js
$(".rezult").html("dfgdf");
$(function() {
  $("input[name='Go']").click(function() {
    var ot = $(".ot").val();
    var doo = $(".do").val();
    var rezutl = doo - ot; //Так работает //НУЖНО ЗАКОММЕНТИРОВАТЬ
    var raund = Math.floor(Math.random() * (ot) + rezutl); //Работает//НУЖНО ЗАКОММЕНТИРОВАТЬ
    //var raund = Math.floor(Math.random() * (ot) + doo); //А так нет
    $(".rezult").html("<h1>" + "Результат: " + raund + "</h1>");

  });
});
```

```css
.ot {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 180px;
  font-size: 57px;
  color: aquamarine;
  margin: 0 14px 0 0;
}

.do {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 180px;
  font-size: 57px;
  color: #59aef1;
}

.button {
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  color: cadetblue;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<center>
  <div class="generator_chisel">
    <h1>Генератор случайных чисел</h1>
    <div class="rezult">

    </div>
    <form action="" name="activ">
      <input type="number" name="ot" class="ot" placeholder="ОТ">
      <input type="number" name="do" class="do" placeholder="ДО"><br>
      <input type="button" name="Go" value="Генерировать" class="button">
    </form>
  </div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы из полей получаете не числа, а строки. Когда вы отнимаете их заранее, то они автоматически преобразуются, т.е. при вычитании, строки преобразуются в числа сами. Чтобы преобразовать строки вручную, я обычно использую [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). Но есть ещё альтернативные функции: [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```js
$(".rezult").html("dfgdf");
$(function() {
  $("input[name='Go']").click(function() {
    var valOt = parseFloat( $(".ot").val() ) || 0,
        valDo = parseFloat( $(".do").val() ) || 100;
  
    var min = valOt > valDo ? valDo : valOt,
        max = valOt > valDo ? valOt : valDo,
        raund = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    
    $(".rezult").html("<h1>" + "Результат: " + raund + "</h1>");
  });
});
```

```css
.ot {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 180px;
  font-size: 57px;
  color: aquamarine;
  margin: 0 14px 0 0;
}

.do {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 180px;
  font-size: 57px;
  color: #59aef1;
}

.button {
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  color: cadetblue;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<center>
  <div class="generator_chisel">
    <h1>Генератор случайных чисел</h1>
    <div class="rezult">

    </div>
    <form action="" name="activ">
      <input type="number" name="ot" class="ot" placeholder="ОТ">
      <input type="number" name="do" class="do" placeholder="ДО"><br>
      <input type="button" name="Go" value="Генерировать" class="button">
    </form>
  </div>
</center>
```

Я и немного усовершенствовал ваш код, добавив в него случаи, если пользователь ничего не введёт, или "от" будет больше чем "до"